# HDF5 doesn't create a file with H5Fcreate() in C++

Tags: c++, file, hdf5, file-writing

**Backgound**

I'm trying to create a HDF5 file to which I write positioning data. The data is written one measurement at a time and the data set size is increased each time to match the current measurement data size. The file has a single dimension data space and the data set contains compound data type that consists of floats and integer numbers.

**Problem**

When I create the file with H5Fcreate() for the first time starting the code running, the HDF5 API registers no errors but doesn't actually create a file. When I close everything down and try to create a new file to a new directory with the same function, the HDF5 API starts to complain about not being able to open a file. This time though, the HDF5 actually creates the file but doesn't write anything to it. Any consequent efforts to create a file end up with the same result.

**Code workflow:**

1. To create a new measurement file init() is called. This creates the HDF5 file and the rest of the HDF5 components (data space etc.)
2. The data recording is enabled by calling startWriting()
3. When new measurements are read from the GNSS system, writeData() is called. When the writing is enabled, the class increases the data space size and stores the new data as compound data to the end of the data set.
4. When the writing is set to stop, stopAndClose() is called. This disables the writing and closes all HDF5 objects.

**Code:**

```
#include "gnssWriter.h"
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

GNSSWriter::GNSSWriter(QString sensorName) :
    fileHandle_(0), compoundType_(0), dataSpace_(0),
    dataSet_(0), propertyList_(0), status_(0),
    sensorName_(sensorName), ready_(false), running_(false)
{
    emit ready(false);
    emit running(false);
}


GNSSWriter::~GNSSWriter()
{
    H5Fclose(fileHandle_);
}

void GNSSWriter::init(QString filePath)
{
    if ( running_ )
    {
        running_ = false;
        ready_   = false;

        emit logMessage("Initialized writer while recording was running. Writing stopped until next start command.");
        closeHDF5();
    }

    initHDF5(filePath);

    ready_ = true;
    emit logMessage("Writer ready.");
    emit ready(true);
}


void GNSSWriter::startWriting()
{
    if ( ready_ )
    {
       running_ = true;
       ready_ = false;
       emit running(true);
       emit ready(false);
       emit logMessage("Writer started.");
    } else
        emit logMessage("Cannot start writing. File path not determined.");
}


void GNSSWriter::stopAndClose()
{
    running_ = false;
    ready_ = false;
    emit running(false);
    emit ready(false);
    emit logMessage("Writer stopped.");

    closeHDF5();
}


void GNSSWriter::writeData(double timeStamp, double lat, double lon, double alt,
                           double heading, double speed, int numOfSatellites, int mode)
{
    emit running(running_);

    if ( running_ )
    {
        GNSSData dataToWrite[1] = {{timeStamp, lat, lon, alt, heading, speed, numOfSatellites, mode}};

        // Increase the data set size
        hsize_t offset[1];
        offset[0] = 0;

        qDebug() << "Start write";
        if ( measCounter_[0] != 1 )
        {
            offset[0] = measCounter_[0];
            measCounter_[0]++;
            H5Dset_extent(dataSet_, measCounter_);
        } else
            measCounter_[0]++;

        qDebug() << "Data set extended";

        // Select the data block to write to
        H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataSpace_, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, NULL, measCounter_, NULL);

        qDebug() << "Hyperslab selected";

        // Write the data
        H5Dwrite(dataSet_, compoundType_, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, dataToWrite);

        qDebug() << "Data written";
    }
}


void GNSSWriter::updateDir(QString filePath)
{
    dir_ = QDir::home();

    if ( !dir_.cd("data") )
    {
        dir_.mkpath("data");
        dir_.cd("data");
    }

    if ( !dir_.cd(filePath) )
    {
        dir_.mkpath(filePath);
        dir_.cd(filePath);
    }

    if ( !dir_.cd("GNSS") )
    {
        dir_.mkpath("GNSS");
        dir_.cd("GNSS");
    }
}

void GNSSWriter::initHDF5(QString filePath)
{
    updateDir(filePath);

    QString path = dir_.path() + "/" + sensorName_;
    QByteArray ba = path.toUtf8();
    const char *pathCharPtr = ba.data();

    ba = sensorName_.toUtf8();
    const char *dataSetNamePtr = ba.data();

    fileHandle_ = H5Fcreate(pathCharPtr, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    qDebug() << "Path string: " << path;

    if ( (int) fileHandle_ < 0 )
        qDebug() << "Failed to create file.";
    else
        qDebug() << "File creation succesful.";

    propertyList_ = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_CREATE);
    hsize_t chunkDimensions[1];
    chunkDimensions[0] = 1;
    H5Pset_chunk(propertyList_, 1, chunkDimensions);

    compoundType_ = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof (GNSSData));

    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Time stamp",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, timeStamp), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Latitude",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, latitude), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Longitude",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, longitude), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Altitude",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, altitude), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Heading",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, heading), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Speed",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, speed), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Number of satellites",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, numOfSats), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    status_ = H5Tinsert (compoundType_, "Mode",
                HOFFSET (GNSSData, mode), H5T_NATIVE_INT);

    hsize_t dims[1];
    dims[0] = 1;
    hsize_t maxDims[1];
    maxDims[0] = MAX_DIMS;

    dataSpace_ = H5Screate_simple(1, dims, maxDims);
    dataSet_ = H5Dcreate(fileHandle_, dataSetNamePtr, compoundType_, dataSpace_, H5P_DEFAULT,
                          propertyList_, H5P_DEFAULT);

    measCounter_[0] = 1;

    GNSSData test[1];

    H5Dwrite(dataSet_, compoundType_, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, test);
}


void GNSSWriter::closeHDF5()
{
    emit logMessage("Closed HDF5 data handling.");

    H5Dclose(dataSet_);
    H5Sclose(dataSpace_);
    H5Tclose(compoundType_);
    H5Fclose(fileHandle_);

    dataSet_      = 0;
    dataSpace_    = 0;
    compoundType_ = 0;
    fileHandle_   = 0;
}
```